# Does JITting occur per-assembly or per-method? How does this affect the working set

Tags: asp.net

Does JITting occur per-assembly or per-method? How does this affect the working set

Answer (score 6):

Per method.  Methods that are not called are not compiled thus reducing impact on the working set.

This may help: [Does the .NET CLR JIT compile every method, every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255803/does-the-net-clr-jit-compile-every-method-every-time)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Daniel.

If you have access to it, Jeffrey Richter's [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) book provides an excellent overview of how JIT'ing occurs and how the CLR handles the results.  It's a clear and concise explanation.