# What's the purpose of the 'short' notation of IL?

Tags: c#, .net, il, opcode

Every time I bumb into them in IL: br_S, ldc_i4_S, ldarg_S, etc, etc... So I just have to ask the question:

I mean... If you're JIT'ing a language from IL to native assembler, it shouldn't really matter in terms of performance, right? So what's the purpose of having these 'short-hand' notations? Is it just for having fewer bytes in the IL binaries (e.g. as a compression mechanism) or is there some other reason?

And if it's just as a compression mechanism, why not use a compression algorithm like deflate?

Comment: @HansPassant Like you probably also did (and the JIT team definately did), I spend quite some time in the `Intel x64-86 [...] instruction set manual`. One thing that really stands out there is that they started with short-hand notations and when the instruction set grew, so did the number of obvious hacks. My lesson learned there was: don't do that, it'll just add a lot of complexity in the long run. With that in mind, using a standard compression algorithm suddenly makes a lot of more sense than short-hand bytecodes, right? Perhaps I'm wrong, I'm just curious...

Comment: I'm on a bit of thin ice here asking for the 'why didn't they do it like that', I realize that... I'm just wondering about the reasons having the historical background in mind. If the reason *is* compression, I realize this is a valid solution that they obviously chose. Just wondering if it's the only one.

Comment: @atlaste You have to remember that perhaps when they created the IL language they were thinking of embedded devices (where memory was a premium) and perhaps of the possibility a possible native IL code microprocessor (Java had [them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor))

Comment: @xanatos Yes, I realize that - that's one of the reasons why I ask. Java uses ZIP compression in their JAR files, which arguably renders the complete compression argument obsolete.

Comment: @atlaste And even java bytecodes have special ops for the first four variables (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings and search for `local variable 0`)

Comment: @xanatos Yes, but you can argue that's for historical reasons (like Intel). In Java 1.0 they started off with class files, which aren't compressed. JAR's were added in version 1.2.

Comment: I'm not sure that compression is a good idea on memory constrained devices... You still have to keep the uncompressed bytecode in memory for reflection. It is surely good on disk and on loading (because there is less data to load), and because it "guarantees" that files don't get lost.

Comment: 'You still have to keep the uncompressed bytecode in memory for reflection.' -- I didn't consider that. As a compression algorithm, I think you get similare results with a static deflate - this is just a lot faster because you can hard-code the 'table'. :-) Still, at the end of the day, I believe you and Hans are right.

Comment: Compression is a pretty ho-hum, always better when you don't have to deal with it.  And you don't, it is but a mouse-click away on Windows.  The file system driver is the best place to do it.

Comment: @atlaste Another important thing: the whole assembly isn't JITted at start... The JIT is "lazy", and JITs a method/class when first called... so it isn't only a reflection problem And by [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1255832/613130), the micro framework interprets and doesn't compile.

Comment: @xanatos Yes I was considering the former - but from another angle: if methods are small, and you want to JIT them lazy, you need random access decompression. That's not really working out for most algorithms, and compression will be seriously hurt on a per-method base for smaller methods (which is the bulk). A short-hand based compression algorithm solves both these issues. Now, I didn't know about the interpreter, but I guess that's basically the same problem, but further expands the need for random access. In short, this is actually a very solid reason to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, it is a micro-optimization.  But the Golden Rule of micro-optimizing applies strongly here, they turn macro when you can apply the optimization over and over again.  Which is certainly the case here, method bodies are small so the vast majority of branches are short ones, methods have a limited number of arguments and local variables so a single byte is enough to address them, the constants 0 through 9 very often appear in a real program.

Add them all up and you have a macro-optimization on a large assembly, many kilobytes shaved-off.  Which *does* matter at runtime, that's IL that doesn't have to page-faulted into RAM.  Warm-start time in a jitted program is always an issue and has been attacked from every possible angle.

In general, the .NET Framework is *relentlessly* micro-optimized.  Largely because Microsoft just can't assume that their code won't be on the critical path in a program.

Comment: If I remember correctly, years ago the JIT phase slowness was a big problem (that has been partially solved by faster processors :-) and partially solved by multithread JITting )

Comment: How is it micro-optimisation. `ldarg_S` etc are mnemonics, not the opcodes themselves, which are byte data, not text. The length of the mnemonics is unrelated to the opcode size.

Comment: The mnemonic is irrelevant, all that matters is that the short version takes fewer bytes in the IL.  ldarg_0 and friends take 1, ldarg_S takes 2, ldarg takes 3 bytes.  If you ever find ldarg back then you found a programmer that needs to be fired :)

Comment: Combined with the last arguments from @xanatos (I'll make sure to give some points) I'll accept this answer. Especially in combination with the interpreter and lazy loading that he mentions, a normal compression algorithm doesn't make sense: that would require you to pre-decompress data 'random access', which will either hurt performance (quite seriously) or data compression ratios. That doesn't make sense, since this simple solution tackles the problem of compression ratio at the expense of 'getting a bit more performance'. :-)

Answer (score 5):

**not a response**: there is already a response, it postulates that without "short" opcodes, the assembly size would bloat. Is it true? Yes... but we have (I have, because I didn't have anything to do this evening) to demonstrate it :-)

How many bytes are "gained" through the use of "short" (in truth `byte`) values for OpCodes (like `Bge_S` vs `Bge`)? And from the use of OpCodes that include a "fixed" index/number? (like `Ldarg_0` vs `Ldarg` or `Ldc_I4_0` and `Ldc_I4_M1` vs `Ldc_I4`)?

We could write a program to check it! :-) The result, for mscorlib 4.5.2:

> 4.5.2 or later
>
> Assembly: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll
>
> Size: 5217440
>
> Of which resources: 948657
>
> Skipped: 9496 methods
>
> Parsed: 63720 methods
>
> Gained 420786 bytes from short arguments
>
> Gained 1062014 bytes from "fixed" number

So with "optimized opcodes" mscorlib is 5.2mb ... Without it would be 6.6mb just for the values sizes. 25% more! (and this ignoring that of 5.2mb, 0.9mb are of resources! So the percentage gain in opcode size is even greater)

(I'm using `mscorlib` because, while it isn't your typical assembly, it is surely quite full of code of every type)

The program: (I'm using [Mono.Reflection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Reflection/)):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(CheckFor45DotVersion(GetReleaseKey()));

    string assemblyName = "mscorlib";
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);

    Console.WriteLine("Assembly: {0}", assembly.Location);

    long fullSize = new FileInfo(assembly.Location).Length;

    Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}", fullSize);

    var allOpCodes = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(x => x.FieldType == typeof(OpCode))
        .Select(x => (OpCode)x.GetValue(null));

    Dictionary<OpCode, int> opcodes = allOpCodes.ToDictionary(x => x, x => 0);

    long resourcesLength = 0;
    int skippedMethods = 0;
    int parsedMethods = 0;

    ParseAssembly(assembly, resource =>
    {
        ManifestResourceInfo info = assembly.GetManifestResourceInfo(resource);

        if (info.ResourceLocation.HasFlag(ResourceLocation.Embedded))
        {
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
            {
                resourcesLength += stream.Length;
            }
        }
    }, method =>
    {
        if (method.MethodImplementationFlags.HasFlag(MethodImplAttributes.InternalCall))
        {
            skippedMethods++;
            return;
        }

        if (method.Attributes.HasFlag(MethodAttributes.PinvokeImpl))
        {
            skippedMethods++;
            return;
        }

        if (method.IsAbstract)
        {
            skippedMethods++;
            return;
        }

        parsedMethods++;

        IList<Instruction> instructions = method.GetInstructions();

        foreach (Instruction instruction in instructions)
        {
            int num;
            opcodes.TryGetValue(instruction.OpCode, out num);
            opcodes[instruction.OpCode] = num + 1;
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Of which resources: {0}", resourcesLength);

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Skipped: {0} methods", skippedMethods);
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed: {0} methods", parsedMethods);

    int gained = 0;
    int gainedFixedNumber = 0;

    // m1: Ldc_I4_M1
    var shortOpcodes = opcodes.Where(x =>
        x.Key.Name.EndsWith(".s") ||
        x.Key.Name.EndsWith(".m1") ||
            // .0 - .9
        x.Key.Name[x.Key.Name.Length - 2] == '.' && char.IsNumber(x.Key.Name[x.Key.Name.Length - 1]));

    foreach (var @short in shortOpcodes)
    {
        OpCode opCode = @short.Key;
        string name = opCode.Name.Remove(opCode.Name.LastIndexOf('.'));
        OpCode equivalentLong = opcodes.Keys.First(x => x.Name == name);

        int lengthShort = GetLength(opCode.OperandType);
        int lengthLong = GetLength(equivalentLong.OperandType);

        int gained2 = @short.Value * (lengthLong - lengthShort);

        if (opCode.Name.EndsWith(".s"))
        {
            gained += gained2;
        }
        else
        {
            gainedFixedNumber += gained2;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Gained {0} bytes from short arguments", gained);
    Console.WriteLine("Gained {0} bytes from \"fixed\" number", gainedFixedNumber);
}

private static int GetLength(OperandType operandType)
{
    switch (operandType)
    {
        case OperandType.InlineNone:
            return 0;

        case OperandType.ShortInlineVar:
        case OperandType.ShortInlineI:
        case OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget:
            return 1;

        case OperandType.InlineVar:
            return 2;

        case OperandType.InlineI:
        case OperandType.InlineBrTarget:
            return 4;

    }

    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

private static void ParseAssembly(Assembly assembly, Action<string> resourceAction, Action<MethodInfo> action)
{
    string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

    foreach (string name in names)
    {
        resourceAction(name);
    }

    Module[] modules = assembly.GetModules();

    foreach (Module module in modules)
    {
        ParseModule(module, action);
    }
}

private static void ParseModule(Module module, Action<MethodInfo> action)
{
    MethodInfo[] methods = module.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
    {
        action(method);
    }

    Type[] types = module.GetTypes();

    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        ParseType(type, action);
    }
}

private static void ParseType(Type type, Action<MethodInfo> action)
{
    if (type.IsInterface)
    {
        return;
    }

    // delegate (in .NET all delegates are MulticastDelegate
    if (type != typeof(MulticastDelegate) && typeof(MulticastDelegate).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        return;
    }

    MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
    {
        action(method);
    }

    Type[] nestedTypes = type.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    foreach (Type nestedType in nestedTypes)
    {
        ParseType(nestedType, action);
    }
}

// Adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx
private static int GetReleaseKey()
{
    using (RegistryKey ndpKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Full\\"))
    {
        // .NET 4.0
        if (ndpKey == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int releaseKey = (int)ndpKey.GetValue("Release");
        return releaseKey;
    }
}

// Checking the version using >= will enable forward compatibility,  
// however you should always compile your code on newer versions of 
// the framework to ensure your app works the same. 
private static string CheckFor45DotVersion(int releaseKey)
{
    if (releaseKey >= 393273)
    {
        return "4.6 RC or later";
    }
    if ((releaseKey >= 379893))
    {
        return "4.5.2 or later";
    }
    if ((releaseKey >= 378675))
    {
        return "4.5.1 or later";
    }
    if ((releaseKey >= 378389))
    {
        return "4.5 or later";
    }
    // This line should never execute. A non-null release key should mean 
    // that 4.5 or later is installed. 
    return "No 4.5 or later version detected";
}
```

---

Inspired by the code of xanatos, the same code using the raw IL bytes might give us an even better estimate of how much we can gain. I've divided the gains / losses into categories to get a good picture.

```
class Program
{
    internal class Calculator
    {
        static Calculator()
        {
            Register(OpCodes.Beq_S, 1, 3); // category 1: short-hand notations
            Register(OpCodes.Bge_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Bge_Un_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Bgt_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Bgt_Un_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Ble_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Ble_Un_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Blt_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Blt_Un_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Bne_Un_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Br_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Brfalse_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_I, 2, 4); // category 2: types can be generalized
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_I1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_I2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_I4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_I8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I1_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I2_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I4_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_I8_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U1_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U2_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U4_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_Ovf_U8_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_R_Un, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_R4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_R8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_U, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_U1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_U2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_U4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Conv_U8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldarg_0, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldarg_1, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldarg_2, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldarg_3, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, 1, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldarga, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldarga_S, 1, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0, 3, 2); // category 3: small value loads
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_5, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_6, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_7, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_8, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_M1, 3, 2);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_I, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_I1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_I2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_I4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_I8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_R4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_R8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_U1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_U2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldelem_U4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_I, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_I1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_I2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_I4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_I8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_R4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_R8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_Ref, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_U1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_U2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldind_U4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldloc_0, 3, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldloc_1, 3, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldloc_2, 3, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldloc_3, 3, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, 1, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, 1, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Leave_S, 1, 3);
            Register(OpCodes.Starg_S, 1, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Stelem_I, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stelem_I1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stelem_I2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stelem_I4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stelem_I8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stelem_R4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stelem_R8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stind_I, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stind_I1, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stind_I2, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stind_I4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stind_I8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stind_R4, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stind_R8, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stind_Ref, 2, 4);
            Register(OpCodes.Stloc_0, 3, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Stloc_1, 3, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Stloc_2, 3, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Stloc_3, 3, 1);
            Register(OpCodes.Stloc_S, 1, 1);
        }

        private Calculator() { }

        private static void Register(OpCode opCode, int category, int delta)
        {
            dict[opCode] = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(category, delta);
        }

        private static Dictionary<OpCode, KeyValuePair<int, int>> dict = new Dictionary<OpCode, KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

        public static void Update(int[] data, OpCode opcode)
        {
            KeyValuePair<int, int> kv;
            if (dict.TryGetValue(opcode, out kv))
            {
                data[kv.Key] += kv.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Decompiler
    {
        public Decompiler() { }

        static Decompiler()
        {
            singleByteOpcodes = new OpCode[0x100];
            multiByteOpcodes = new OpCode[0x100];
            FieldInfo[] infoArray1 = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields();
            for (int num1 = 0; num1 < infoArray1.Length; num1++)
            {
                FieldInfo info1 = infoArray1[num1];
                if (info1.FieldType == typeof(OpCode))
                {
                    OpCode code1 = (OpCode)info1.GetValue(null);
                    ushort num2 = (ushort)code1.Value;
                    if (num2 < 0x100)
                    {
                        singleByteOpcodes[(int)num2] = code1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((num2 & 0xff00) != 0xfe00)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Invalid opcode: " + num2.ToString());
                        }
                        multiByteOpcodes[num2 & 0xff] = code1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static OpCode[] singleByteOpcodes;
        private static OpCode[] multiByteOpcodes;

        public int[] Delta = new int[5];

        public void Decompile(MethodBase mi, byte[] ildata)
        {
            Module module = mi.Module;

            int position = 0;
            while (position < ildata.Length)
            {
                OpCode code = OpCodes.Nop;

                ushort b = ildata[position++];
                if (b != 0xfe)
                {
                    code = singleByteOpcodes[b];
                }
                else
                {
                    b = ildata[position++];
                    code = multiByteOpcodes[b];
                    b |= (ushort)(0xfe00);
                    Delta[4]++;
                }

                switch (code.OperandType)
                {
                    case OperandType.InlineBrTarget:
                        position += 4;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineField:
                        position += 4;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineI:
                        position += 4;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineI8:
                        position += 8;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineMethod:
                        position += 4;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineNone:
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineR:
                        position += 8;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineSig:
                        position += 4;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineString:
                        position += 4;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineSwitch:
                        int count = BitConverter.ToInt32(ildata, position);
                        position += count * 4 + 4;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineTok:
                    case OperandType.InlineType:
                        position += 4;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.InlineVar:
                        position += 2;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget:
                        position += 1;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.ShortInlineI:
                        position += 1;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.ShortInlineR:
                        position += 4;
                        break;
                    case OperandType.ShortInlineVar:
                        position += 1;
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Unknown instruction operand; cannot continue. Operand type: " + code.OperandType);
                }

                Calculator.Update(Delta, code);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string assemblyName = "mscorlib";
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);

        int skippedMethods = 0;
        int parsedMethods = 0;
        Decompiler decompiler = new Decompiler();

        long totalbytes = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Assembly: {0}", assembly.Location);
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            foreach (var method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance))
            {
                if (method.MethodImplementationFlags.HasFlag(MethodImplAttributes.InternalCall) ||
                    method.Attributes.HasFlag(MethodAttributes.PinvokeImpl) ||
                    method.IsAbstract)
                {
                    skippedMethods++;
                }
                else
                {
                    var body = method.GetMethodBody();
                    byte[] bytes;
                    if (body != null && (bytes = body.GetILAsByteArray()) != null)
                    {
                        decompiler.Decompile(method, bytes);
                        ++parsedMethods;

                        totalbytes += bytes.Length;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        skippedMethods++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var delta = decompiler.Delta;

        Console.WriteLine("{0} methods parsed, {1} methods skipped", parsedMethods, skippedMethods);
        Console.WriteLine("- {0} bytes total", totalbytes);
        Console.WriteLine("- {0} bytes gained from generalizing short-hand notations", delta[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("- {0} bytes gained from generalizing type notations", delta[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("- {0} bytes gained from generalizing loads notations", delta[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("- {0} bytes lost from multi-byte opcodes", delta[4]);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The results:

```
Assembly: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll
56117 methods parsed, 10605 methods skipped
- 2489275 bytes total
- 361193 bytes gained from generalizing short-hand notations
- 126724 bytes gained from generalizing type notations
- 618858 bytes gained from generalizing loads notations
- 9447 bytes lost from multi-byte opcodes
```

What does this say? First, total is based on the actual IL bytes of the methods. Short-hand notation gains are the number of bytes gained from not using the `_S` opcodes. Type notation generalizations are opcodes that could have been generalized by using a type token instead of the opcode specialization (e.g. conversions like `conv_i4`). Load gains are bytes that would be gained from load specializations (e.g. `ldc_i4_0`). And finally because they now have too many opcodes to fit in a byte, IL also needs a few more bytes.

Total gain from all of this means that we would have a DLL of size 3586603 instead of 2489275 bytes - which totals a compression ratio of +/- 30%.

Comment: Nice experiment. To be honest, I'm actually quite surprised it isn't way more.

Comment: @atlaste Probably a good piece of space is used for types, method calls and signatures

Comment: Nice. But wouldn't it be more in the spirit of SO to actually augment/improve Hans' answer?

Comment: @xanatos I've taken the liberty of adding the same code using IL byte code, so that we don't get a 'blurred' answer due to the metadata / field / etc tokens in the DLL's. I think the total compression ratio is an important factor that tells a lot about the gains, at no real expense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

End of the day short codes attempt to make 'smaller' code. Does not really make any semantic difference.

Answer (score -1):

It is not due to compression, as each byte has a "name-representation".

Meaning that the byte `0x00` (which represents the command **nop**) is stored as `00` and not as `6e 6f 70` (being the ASCII-Version of the string "`nop`").
These 'short' notataions are short due to debugging purposes - even if `ldarg.0` is a bit harder to read than `Load argument 0 onto the stack`.

A full list of CIL commands can be viewed here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions

---

*Do please excuse my rather simplistic explanations due to my unfamiliarity of the English language*

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...? Of course we store byte codes, that's just way more convenient. Now, `ldarg.0` isn't harder to read than `ldarg 0`, `ldc_i4_0` isn't harder to read than `ldc_i4 0` and `br_s 0x10` isn't harder to read than `br 0x10` - they just add more instructions to the table, which means they needed multi-byte opcodes, more code in their 'switch' table in the JIT, etc.

Comment: @atlaste: Do please excuse me, Sir - I seem to have misunderstood the question......

Comment: You seem to be the only one who's answered correctly: that the opcodes aren't stored as, eg a byte 0xD7, rather than the string "add.ovf.un", I don't follow you reasoning regarding the debugger though.